# How to disable tracking of a dependency in configure script

Tags: configure, autoconf, automake

I am trying to build a library with a different build system, but files in the library require a `config.h` header file that is generated after running the configure scripts generated by autoconf.

This is the sequence of steps I am following to try and generate the `config.h` file that is needed

```
autoreconf -ivf 
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking
```

The build system guarantees that the library `gflags` will be linked and the headers will be available at preprocessing time.  But the `configure` script exits with the following error

```
configure: error: Please install google-gflags library
```

Is there some way I can get the list of required libraries (such as gflags) and then pass arguments to the configure script that tells it to assume that this library exists on the system?  I went through the help output for both `autoreconf` and `./configure` and wasn't able to figure this out.

Sorry for the long explanation and problem.  I am very new to `autoconf`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is: *no, it is not possible to get a list of dependencies from autotools*.

### Why?

Well, autotools doesn't track dependencies at all.
Instead, it checks whether specific features are present on the system (e.g. a given header-file; or a given library file).
Now a specific header file can come from a variety of sources, e.g. depending on your distribution the `foo.h` header can be installed via

- `libfoo-dev` (Debian and derivatives)
- `foo-devel` (Fedora)
- `foo` (upstream)
- ...

In your specific case, the maintainers of your project output a nice error message telling you to install a given package by name.

The maintainers of your project also chose to abort with a fatal error if a given dependency is not available.
The reason might well be, that the project simply won't work without that dependency, and that is impossible to compile the program without it.

#### Example

Your project might be written in `C++` and thus require a `C++`-compiler.
Obviously there is little use in *passing some flags to ./configure so it **assumes** that there is a C++-compiler available* if in reality there is none.

### There is hope

However, not all is bad.
Your `configure` script might will have the ability to disable certain features (that appear to be hard requirements by default).

Just check `./configure --help` and look for flags like

- `--enable-FOO`
- `--disable-FOO`
- `--with-BAR`
- `--without-BAR`

#### automation?

One thing to know about autotools, is that `configure` really is a program (the source-code being `configure.ac`) written in some arcane programming language (involving `bash` and `m4`),
This means that it can practically have *any* behavior, and there is no single standard way to achieve "dependecy tracking".

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do will not work as umläute already said. On the other hand, depending on the package you're trying to build, you may be able to tell `./configure` that a given library is there even if it isn't.

For instance if the script uses `pkg-config` to check for the presence of a library, you can use `FOO_CFLAGS` and `FOO_LIBS` to override the presence checking and telling it "yes those packages are there, you just don't know how to find them", but these are very package-specific so you may have to provide more information if that's what you're looking for.